# Query about tab creation events in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

At http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#demo i found below description about create event on tab wizard. To me look like  both ways attach the callback function with create event. But i am sure there must be some difference in their usage. **Is it first approach should be used at the time of creation tab and second one is applicable once tabs has been constructed?**

//Approach 1

```
Supply a callback function to handle the create event as an init option.
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   create: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

//Approach 2

```
Bind to the create event by type: tabscreate.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabscreate", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they're equivalent. They both enable you to run code when a tabs instance is [created](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-create).  I would say the first method is a little more common than the second. Although someone on the jQuery UI team needs to update the reference to the deprecated `.bind()` function.